# Invoke-Sqlcmd returning error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am trying to use **Invoke-Sqlcmd** command in PowerShell (version 7):

```
$Server = 'localhost'
$Database = 'db'
$Query = "PRINT 'This is output'"
$Username = 'root'
$Password = 'pass'
Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -ConnectionTimeout 2 -QueryTimeout 5 -Query $Query
```

But getting error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
> while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
> found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
> and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
> Server/Instance Specified) Invoke-Sqlcmd:

I can connect to DB using **Workbench** and using **mysql** command from powershell, but **Invoke-Sqlcmd** returns this error every time, can anyone point me where the problem is?

Comment: Are you trying to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` against a MySQL instance? That isn't going to work... As the error tells you, it's for connecting to **SQL Server**, *not* MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my bad, installed MySQL Connector and now can connect to MySQL Server. Thanks again for pointing that!

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu pointed - I tried to use Invoke-Sqlcmd to connect to MySQL Server which will not work, so I installed MySQL Connector and now able to connect using

```
$Mysqlhost= "127.0.0.1"
$Mysqluser= "user"
$Mysqlpass= "pass"
$Mysqldatabase= "db"
​
$Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString="server=$Mysqlhost;uid=$Mysqluser;pwd=$Mysqlpass;database=$Mysqldatabase"}
$Connection.Open()
$sql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql.Connection = $Connection
```

Maybe will be useful for someone.
Thanks to Larnu for pointing to my error.